# Using Joomla, htaccess won't forward pages without an extension to the correct 404 page?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, http-status-code-404, errordocument

At LTCperformance.com, I've created a custom 404 page. If the user types in ltcperformance.com/fakepage.html, it forwards to the 404 page. But if there's no extension (ltcperformance.com/fakepage), it simply shows a default system 404 page.

I'm controlling the 404 page using htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://ltcperformance.com/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 http://ltcperformance.com/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://ltcperformance.com/404.php
```

I have URL Rewriting in Joomla Administrator = on
Also, in Joomla Administrator, the Adds Suffix to URL = off

Any ideas? I've gone through every answer I can find on other posts and nothing will bring up my custom 404 page if there isn't an extension on the file.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
Any non-existent pages go to the homepage when I do these settings:
- Search Engine Friendly URLs / NO
- Use URL rewriting /Yes
- Adds Suffix to URL /No

I have someone taking a look at it on the server side, but I don't know what server issue it is - everybody online says it's a server issue but the support can't pinpoint what the actual server issue is. It's Godaddy; I did set their 404 page settings (they have a separate place to put it) to my 404 page, but that didn't work either.

Comment: When you say 'default system 404 page' do you mean Joomla's 404 page or  the server's 404 page?

Comment: David - I believe it's the server's 404 page.

Comment: anybody have any help on this? I'm still getting this error!

Answer (score 0):

Joomla .htaccess routes all requests to the index.php in order to support SEF urls.

In case it can't route a page, it will load the templates' error.php page. You can edit that to your requirements, this will be the easiest.

Should the error.php not be included in your template, copy the one in /templates/system to your template folder and customize it.

Comment: Riccardo - Thanks for your response. I followed their directions to do this, but it would make all the pages go to the 404 page (the right one), even pages that existed except for the home page.

Comment: I suggest you stick with the default Joomla 404 behaviour i.e. htaccess.txt that's shipped with Joomla, and customize the error.php in your template (or redirect from it). The default Joomla! htaccess routes all missing pages, regardless of the extension.

Comment: Riccardo - I edited the error.php page, but it still isn't forwarding to that page. I just get a default 404 page: http://ltcperformance.com/asdf

Comment: @Kimberly are you using the default .htaccess from Joomla distribution? If not can you replace your current one with the default one and retest?

Comment: If I remove the htaccess coding that forces a 404 page, it will use the error.php page but not for extension-less pages (ltcperformance.com/alskdjf

Comment: Why don't you bring this up to your host /provider? they could have some uncommon configuration and have a solution ready...